# How do I add a node to a sublevel of sysctl?

Tags: linux, kernel-module

`register_sysctl_table` adds a table/node to the top level of the sysctl tree. How would a Linux kernel module add a table/node to a sublevel of sysctl? For example, if I wanted to add a table to `kernel`, what would I do to add it? Similarly, how would one *un*register a non-top level sysctl node?

Comment: "how would one unregister a non-top level sysctl node?" - There is function `unregister_sysctl_table`. But calling it requires `ctl_table_header` object, so you cannot do that outside of the driver which registers it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev That is not specific enough to be an answer. If a kernel module created `kernel.node`, would `unregister_sysctl_table` unregister *just* `kernel.node` or `kernel` and everyone of its descendants?

Comment: "If a kernel module created kernel.node, would unregister_sysctl_table unregister just kernel.node or kernel and everyone of its descendants?" - There are several "register" functions which returns `ctl_table_header*` object. When you pass this object to `unregister_sysctl_table`, then it reverts the effect of that "register" call.

Comment: "For example, if I wanted to add a table to kernel, what would I do to add it?" - It seems that you could simply create your `kernel` table and do not bother whether it is already existed or not. E.g. many drivers adds `dev` table: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10.3/source/drivers/char/hpet.c#L1062, https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10.3/source/drivers/cdrom/cdrom.c#L3733, https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10.3/source/drivers/scsi/scsi_sysctl.c#L42.